# "This assignment is for the full term of the assigned rights" - meaning

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, translation, agreement

I try to understand what does

> "This assignment is for the full term of the assigned rights"

mean in the following paragraph:

> The Consultant hereby assigns to the Client all of its Intellectual
>   Property Rights in the Deliverables, excluding the Intellectual
>   Property Rights in the Client Materials. **This assignment is for the
>   full term of the assigned rights**, including all extensions, renewals,
>   reversions and revivals, and includes the right to bring proceedings
>   for past infringements of the assigned rights.

As far as I could get it - it means that the assignment of the rights is lifetime for the objects of Intellectual Property.

Am I wrong?

Comment: I think this would be more on topic at http://law.stackexchange.com

Comment: In the US, intellectual property rights are time limited (by term, circumstances, and other things).  Client wants to assure you, Consultant, that you're giving up any claims to your work for the longest possible time.  Likely this is redundant, since they've already claimed "all" rights, but lawyers like to be sure, and we can't rule out that Client just wants to rub it in.

Comment: @childofsoong Thank you. Will go there next time I will have an issue with "law English"